# opengl glBegin(GL_LINES) and glBegin(GL_POINT) in 2D not visualizing point vector

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics, 2d, glut

I'm making a simple 2D ping - pong game. Now I need to visualize both the players (two lines, one at the top of the screen and one at the bottom) and the ball also. However I don't know why the ball just isn't visualizing... Here is part of the code.

```
 void displayScene()
    {
     glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        glColor3f(0, 0, 0);
        glLineWidth(33);
        glBegin(GL_LINES);
                glColor3f(0, 1, 0);
                glVertex2i(topPlayer->getLeftX(), topPlayer->getLeftY());
                glVertex2i(topPlayer->getRightX(), topPlayer->getRightY());
                glColor3f(1, 0, 0);
                glVertex2i(bottomPlayer->getLeftX(), bottomPlayer->getLeftY());
                glVertex2i(bottomPlayer->getRightX(), bottomPlayer->getRightY());
        glEnd();
        if (ball)
        {
            glPointSize(50);
            glColor3f( 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f );
            glBegin(GL_POINT);
                    glColor3f(1, 0, 0);
                    glVertex2i(ball->getX(), ball->getY());
                    ball->moveBall();
            glEnd();
        }
            glFlush();
    }

    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
        glutInit(&argc, argv);
        glutInitWindowSize(1920, 1080);
        glutCreateWindow("Ping - Pong");
        glClearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
        glOrtho(0, 1920, 1080, 0, -1, 1);
        topPlayer->setLeftY(1);
        topPlayer->setRightY(1);
        bottomPlayer->setLeftY(1920 - 1);
        bottomPlayer->setRightY(1080 - 1);
        glutDisplayFunc(displayScene);
        glutMainLoop();
        return 0;
    }
```

PS: `ball->moveBall();` just changes the ball `x` and `y`. As far debugging the business logic seems good and the x, y coordinates change the way they have to. However the problem is with the visualization of the ball.

PS PS: I know that glBegin is deprecated but I have to use legacy code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> glBegin(GL_POINT);
> ```

That's just generating a `GL_INVALID_ENUM` error (you really should add some error checking to your code, at least for debug builds). The correct enum value is `GL_POINTS`.

However, all of that is *horribly* outdated. `Begin/End` has basically been superseded by vertex arrays back in 1997, and by buffer objects somewhere around 2003, and the whole fixed-function pipeline by shaders back in 2004. If you're doing OpenGL in 2018, there is really no reason to stick to 20 year old concepts which are all *removed* from modern core profiles of OpenGL.

**UPDATE on GL Error Checking**

The most basic way is to call [`glGetError()`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glGetError.xhtml) at "strategic places" in your code. Note that this might force implicit synchronizations in your GL implementation, so it might negatively affect performance. A good strategy is to use that only in debug builds (or other compile-time options).

A much better approach nowadays is GL's [Debug Output](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Debug_Output) feature, where the driver can tell you exactly what is wrong. For example, in the case of using `GL_POINT` for a primitive type, the nivida linux driver reports:

```
GL_INVALID_ENUM error generated. Invalid primitive mode.
```

Comment: I did add a section about error checking to the answer.